unable to login with domain
I am trying to setup a ubuntu gnome 22.04 for login to domain. eventually I will use this box for vmware instant clone pool.
all recommended steps are done to the VM.
when I run "sudo login" the resulting error is "system error"
I don't have a clue what the problem is. a couple of websites said something about the user needing to be able to sudo which I added that permission. Also, I confirmed the VM is showing in the Microsoft active directory.
so I am asking; do you have experience with making Ubuntu login to Microsoft domain? if so how did you do it?
the second question is, how do I get logs for this error?

Do you have a user called login? Please look up what the sudo command does.
